# Separate nav drops must have separate content, showing the same content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two drop nav in navbar on my website and I want that every drop nav display its own div, I'm still beginner in JS, can I get some help.
and thanks.

Its showing the same content on drop nav. Here is the code snippet to check.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDropnav");
function w3_open() {
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
function w3_close() {
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
}
```

```html
  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>  
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-black">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_open()">Dropnav <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_open()">Dropnav1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
</ul>

<nav class="w3-dropnav w3-card-2" style="display:none" id="myDropnav">
  <div class="w3-container">
  <span onclick="w3_close('dropnav')" class="w3-closebtn w3-xlarge" title="Close Menu">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-bottom">
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>HTML/CSS</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn </a>
    <a href="#">Learn </a>
    <a href="#">Learn </a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>JavaScript</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn JavaScript</a>
    <a href="#">Learn jQuery</a>
    <a href="#">Learn AppML</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>Graphics</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn Canvas</a>
    <a href="#">Learn SVG</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</nav>
<nav class="w3-dropnav w3-card-2" style="display:none" id="myDropnav">
  <div class="w3-container">
  <span onclick="w3_close('dropnav')" class="w3-closebtn w3-xlarge" title="Close Menu">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-bottom">
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>HTML/CSS</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn HTML</a>
    <a href="#">Learn CSS</a>
    <a href="#">Learn W3.CSS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>JavaScript</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn JavaScript</a>
    <a href="#">Learn jQuery</a>
    <a href="#">Learn AppML</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>Graphics</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn Canvas</a>
    <a href="#">Learn SVG</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</nav>

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>Click on the "Dropnav" button to toggle the dropnav menu.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig: Why do you have removed the css includes? In this way, the example does not work anymore.

Comment: That was sugget from a user or someone in this site web and I don't know how I edit the code again

Answer (score 0):

For your example you may change the code as follows:

Add the identifier of the menu to the click event.

```
...
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close('myDropnav2');w3_open('myDropnav1');">Dropnav 1<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close('myDropnav1');w3_open('myDropnav2');">Dropnav 2<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
...
```

Change the identifiers of the menu to be unique .

```
...
<nav class="w3-dropnav w3-card-2" style="display:none" id="myDropnav1">
   <div class="w3-container">
      <span onclick="w3_close('myDropnav1')" class="w3-closebtn w3-xlarge" title="Close Menu">&times;</span>
...
<nav class="w3-dropnav w3-card-2" style="display:none" id="myDropnav2">
   <div class="w3-container">
      <span onclick="w3_close('myDropnav2')" class="w3-closebtn w3-xlarge" title="Close Menu">&times;</span>
...
```

Take the identifier of the current menu into account.

```
function w3_open(id) {
   var x = document.getElementById(id);
   if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
      x.className += " w3-show";
   } else {
      x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
   }
}
function w3_close(id) {
   var x = document.getElementById(id);
   x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function w3_open(identifier) {
    w3_close();
    var x = document.getElementById(identifier);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
function w3_close() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dropnav-identifier');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element, index) {
    element.className = element.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
});
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>  
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-black">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_open('myDropnav')">Dropnav <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_open('myDropnav1')">Dropnav1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
</ul>

<nav class="w3-dropnav w3-card-2 dropnav-identifier" style="display:none" id="myDropnav">
  <div class="w3-container">
  <span onclick="w3_close('dropnav')" class="w3-closebtn w3-xlarge" title="Close Menu">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-bottom">
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>HTML/CSS</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn </a>
    <a href="#">Learn </a>
    <a href="#">Learn </a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>JavaScript</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn JavaScript</a>
    <a href="#">Learn jQuery</a>
    <a href="#">Learn AppML</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>Graphics</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn Canvas</a>
    <a href="#">Learn SVG</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</nav>
<nav class="w3-dropnav w3-card-2 dropnav-identifier" style="display:none" id="myDropnav">
  <div class="w3-container">
  <span onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-closebtn w3-xlarge" title="Close Menu">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-bottom">
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>HTML/CSS</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn HTML</a>
    <a href="#">Learn CSS</a>
    <a href="#">Learn W3.CSS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>JavaScript</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn JavaScript</a>
    <a href="#">Learn jQuery</a>
    <a href="#">Learn AppML</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>Graphics</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn Canvas</a>
    <a href="#">Learn SVG</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</nav>
  <nav class="w3-dropnav w3-card-2" style="display:none" id="myDropnav1">
  <div class="w3-container">
  <span onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-closebtn w3-xlarge" title="Close Menu">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-bottom">
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>This is nav 2</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn HTML nav 2</a>
    <a href="#">Learn CSS nav 2</a>
    <a href="#">Learn W3.CSS nav 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>JavaScript nav 2</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn JavaScript nav2</a>
    <a href="#">Learn jQuery nav 2</a>
    <a href="#">Learn AppML nav 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
    <h3>Graphics nav 2</h3>
    <a href="#">Learn Canvas nav 2</a>
    <a href="#">Learn SVG nav 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</nav>

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>Click on the "Dropnav" button to toggle the dropnav menu.</p>
</div>
```

You can do this by sending relevant data while calling w3_open() function.

Comment: can you explain that for me or do you new place that explain that method because i can't understand clearly how it work and thank you

Comment: Actually when we call w3_open() method it was previously written to open only one nav content. What I did is create two nav content give them different ids to identify them and now while call w3_open(identifier), I send the identifier as well by which I can identify which drop down button is pressed and hence can show only content of that nav. Happy coding. :)